# Trying to get info out of an object within and object PHP

Tags: php

Ok, I'm very new to PHP. I will try my best to explain my question.

This is a var_dump of a json object. 
What i am trying to do is access the information in the 'register_sale_products' object.
It contains product info like SKU, Price etc of the products in each sale. In the example below i am trying to list the SKU's.

```
object(stdClass)[1]
  public 'register_sales' => 
    array
      0 => 
        object(stdClass)[2]
          public 'id' => string '7c969b77-6825-bc65-3e04-64f922a570eb' (length=36)
          public 'register_id' => string '07709f8e-8d90-11e0-8e09-4040f540b50a' (length=36)
          public 'invoice_number' => string 'BH8464' (length=6)
          public 'register_sale_products' => 
            array
              ...
          public 'totals' => 
            object(stdClass)[6]
              ...
          public 'register_sale_payments' => 
            array
              ...
      1 => 
        object(stdClass)[9].......
```

I managed to get one SKU from the first "Product" object array 'register_sale_products' using this code.

```
$array = array()    ;
foreach($data->register_sales as $sale){
    $array =    $sale->register_sale_products ;
    }
foreach($array as $saleprod){
        $details = explode(' / ', $saleprod->sku);
    $result = $details[0];
    }
echo $result;
```

I really need to get an a result of each object in the array. 
Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Hard to see in json format, can you json_decode and dump php array instead?

Comment: -1 http://www.emilvikstrom.se/whyidownvote.html (What's your question? What's the goal?)

Comment: You can't actually see the info inside the child array from a var_dump. But i will add to original question. I would love to know why question got down voted. Is it too vague, or too beginner?

Comment: The outcome is to list the SKU's from the products sold in the "register_sales_products". Or any of those values. i.e. "price", "register_id"

Comment: hi @EmilVikström . I read you reason page. I think it's fair. I do wait till i've tried for at least an hour before posting. I am very new. Learning on Lynda.com for 2 weeks now. So stackoverflow is pretty valuable resource and i appreciate any help i can get from here. I will try and make sure my posts are clearer in the future. Thanks

Comment: @EmilVikström and Allen, question has been rewritten. Please consider un-downvoting, and hopefully it's better worded to help you help me. I've really stuck on this and i'm sure the answer is easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwriting `$result` every time this loops:

```
foreach($array as $saleprod){
    $details = explode(' / ', $saleprod->sku);
    $result = $details[0];
}
echo $result;
```

What you have to do is `echo` inside the loop, let `$result` be a new array or let `$result` be a string which you append to:

```
foreach($array as $saleprod){
    $details = explode(' / ', $saleprod->sku);
    echo $details[0], '<br>';
}

// or
$result = array();
foreach($array as $saleprod){
    $details = explode(' / ', $saleprod->sku);
    $result[] = $details[0];
}
foreach($result as $r) {
    echo $r;
}

//or
$result = '';
foreach($array as $saleprod){
    $details = explode(' / ', $saleprod->sku);
    $result .= $details[0] . ' ';
}
echo $result;
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your format correctly, this should create an array of SKUs (note: not a set, any duplicate SKUs will be in the array multiple times).

```
$skus = array();
// Outer loop over sales
foreach($data->register_sales as $sale) {
  // Inner loop over a sale's products
  foreach($sale->register_sale_products as $product) {
    // Add the SKU to the array
    list($skus[]) = explode(' / ', $product->sku);
  }
}

// $skus now contains all the SKUs
print_r($skus);
```

Just for a bit of context, the main issue with your solution (again, based on my interpretation of your structure) is that you overwrite `$array` for each sale, rather than merging `$sale->register_sale_products` into the array (e.g. `$array = array_merge($array, $sale->register_sale_products);`).

However, further improvement can be made by use of the inner loop, as this avoids effectively looping over `$data->register_sales` twice.

The use of `list` on line 7 is optional, but allows the assignment to happen without the extra variable `$details`.